# How to prevent a button from remaining highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I've my first endavour into javascript and jquery (mobile) but now ran into something that I just can't get resolved.

I have a simple form with 4 buttons, when one is clicked a command is submitted to the server (using ajax). Thing is with the interface, that the button clicked (lightgrey to begin with) turns blue and does not return to its original state. Not even when another button is clicked, so after a few clicks, all buttons are blue.

[Here is a link to a test page](http://www.thijsschreijer.nl/test/gashaard/) (with ajax commands disabled)

And this is the page;

```
<div id="mainPageHaard" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="index.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" >Back</a>
        <h1>Haard</h1>
        <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" >Home</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <a id="btnHaardMax" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u">Maximaal</a>
        <a id="btnHaardUp" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Harder</a>
        <a id="btnHaardDown" data-role="button" data-icon="minus">Zachter</a>
        <a id="btnHaardMin" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-d">Waakvlam</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#configPageHaard" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Config</a>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

And the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btnHaardMax").click(function(){
        //SendEvent("Gashaard_MAX", 18);
        return true; 
    });
    $("#btnHaardUp").click(function(){
        //SendEvent("Gashaard_UP", 18);
        return true; 
    });
    $("#btnHaardDown").click(function(){
        //SendEvent("Gashaard_DOWN", 18);
        return true; 
    });
    $("#btnHaardMin").click(function(){
        //SendEvent("Gashaard_MIN", 18);
        return true; 
    });
    $("#btnHaardStart").click(function(){
        //SendEvent("Gashaard_START", 18);
        return true; 
    });
    $("#btnHaardStop").click(function(){
        //SendEvent("Gashaard_STOP", 18);
        return true; 
    });

});
```

I suspect it to be something silly, but would appreciate if someone could point me exactly at the sillyness in my code

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**
you need to remove the css class `ui-btn-active` on the mouse event onclick is finished.

**How? you say?**

```
  $().ready(function(){
    $('some-selector').mousedown(function(){
      $('some-selector').addClass('ui-btn-active');
    })
    $('some-selector').mouseup(function(){
      $('some-selector').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
    })
  })
```

Comment: That didn't resolve my issue directly, but you triggered me on '_removeClass('ui-btn-active')_', and I found the solution. Its related to a bug in jq-mobile 1.0a4, see this post[link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/alpha-1-0a4-1-button-bug-active-theme-applied-and-remains)

Comment: No, i have never used jq-mobile, and i have no idea of how the inner workings of your application is. So i could only give you a general solution. So i provided the answer of what needed to be done dom/html wise, and provided an example of how this can be done with jquery. Anyways, im happy my random keypresses lead you to an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that once you press a button, you disable it until the AJAX call has completed, to avoid accidental double-pressing, or if it doesn't make sense to press the button again, leave it disabled.  Since your buttons are not real buttons but links, see [how to disable/enable buttons and other form elements](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-disable-enable-buttons-and-other-form-elements).  You'll still need to fiddle with the link's class names to stop them looking like they're active or enabled, like `netbrain` suggests.

IMHO, I would use *real* HTML buttons.

Comment: Disabling the buttons would not make sense, as the server side code only starts executing after the ajax call returns. So the user still hasn't seen any effects even then. Nevertheless, its a helpful link for a newbie, Thx!

Comment: So the AJAX call tells the server to queue something which is executed at some time in the future?  If so, I guess that's OK, but it is still a nice extra to indicate something is happening in the meantime, i.e. by using a spinner animation or simply by disabling the button temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a pretty general solution for most people not wanting this default behavior.  take notice that you need the [normalized vclick event](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html).

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $("div[data-role=footer]  a").live('vclick', function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-btn-active");
});
```